# Remover colchetes "[ ]" do retorno em json

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tenho uma api que me retorna um array em JSON, da seguinte forma:

```
[{"Pessoa_contato":"EUZEBIO"}]
```

Porém não estou conseguindo retornar sem estes colchetes, como minha aplicação necessita:

```
{"Pessoa_contato":"EUZEBIO"}
```

Este é o script deste retorno:

```
try {
    if (class_exists($classe)) {
        if (method_exists($classe, $metodo)) {
            $retorno = call_user_func_array(array(new $classe, $metodo), 
                $parametros);
            return json_encode(array( $retorno));
        } else {
            return json_encode(array('Método inexistente!'));
        }
    } else {
        return json_encode(array('Classe inexistente!'));
    }   
}
```

Comment: só fazer assim no retorno `return json_encode($retorno);` acho que é isso, não tenho mais informação então é no chutometro

Answer (score 2):

Caro uma sugestão de solução.

Primeiro um json deve possuir chave e valor `"a":"b"`

logo:

```
  return json_encode(array('Método inexistente!'));
    }
} else {
    return json_encode(array('Classe inexistente!'));
```

não irá gerar nem **um array** valido nem **um json** valido

Sobre o problema em si, remover o método `array()` parece ser suficiente

abraços.

Comment: Em resumo, os colchetes significam array, você está encapsulando de propósito o $retorno dentro de uma array...